# AWK condition failing for a large file but works on a smaller file

Tags: awk

I have a script that is comparing two files and outputting the values if a condition is met.The script works well if I reduce the records in my second file but fails if I use the actual file with 100000 records. What could I be doing wrong? Here is my code

`awk -F '|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1"|"$2]=$3}NR!=FNR{if(exist a[$1"|"$3]) {print "update inventory set amount=" a[$1"|"$3] " where balance_id=" $2 " and balance_type_id=3019;"}}' cash.txt test.txt > update.sql`

```
Cash.txt
0|3019|0
1|3019|1
2|3019|2
3|3019|3
4|3019|4
5|3019|5
6|3019|5

test.txt
0|0|3019
1|1|3019
2|2|3019
3|3|3019
4|4|3019
5|5|3019
6|6|3019
7|7|3019
8|8|3019
9|9|3019
10|10|3019
11|11|3019
12|12|3019
```

Comment: When I test your attempted code, it works fine for me(printing contents on terminal), any error are you getting after running your code? If yes, then kindly do mention that in your question, that will help us to help you, thank you.

Comment: No just not writing the sql file for instances where the files are large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F '[|\r]' 'NR == FNR {
   map[$1 "|" $2] = $3
   next
}
$1 "|" $3 in map {
   print "update inventory set amount=" map[$1 "|" $3] " where balance_id=" $2 " and balance_type_id=3019;"
}' cash.txt test.txt > update.sql
```

By not using `next` in first block your awk is evaluating `FNR != NR` condition for each record in first file and then for each record of second bigger file.

Also second block can be just `$1 "|" $3 in map` so that we process only matching records.

Comment: This behaves like my script works well with small data but an issue with large files

Comment: This can process hundreds of thousands of records. Please try it once and check timings.

Comment: have tried can generate sample files or share mine so that you can try

Comment: Here is a link to the files http://167.71.170.239/cash.txt  and http://167.71.170.239/test.txt

Comment: Any luck getting issue?

Comment: You have DOS line breaks in both of your input files. I have modified my answer to address that. It took `0.11 sec` to process your data with this.

Comment: @kevin : 100k records is a small file in the AWK world. Once i tried pushing mawk2 on my 2018 macbook pro, i have this 1.82 GB flat .txt file filled with unicode - 12.5 million rows and normally 14 columns. I changed FS to the normal intra-row delimiter, plus \n, and asked mawk2 to read it all it and split into fields. Took 31 seconds or so, finished splitting, and gave me back a NF of 173 million

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto thats amazing...Trying to learn awk and use python to call it...

Comment: @kevin : if you can .. .i'll actually recommend doing any heavy bigdata analytics in awk. just the fact my run-time interpreted awk scripts doing URL encode/decode beats the built-in module in python3, or awk script emulating cut would be faster than compiled binary inside macOS, or tail, even fgrep at times, tells you everything you need to know about the absolute insanity that is awk (but those are only attainable using mawk2 beta (aka mawk 1.9.9.6). gawk, as great as it is, is usually much slower, owing mostly to the speed differential of its regex engine,.